# How to managing mecanim animation event more efficiently?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm usually using the parent script object and child is a model and animator. However, this is inconvenient to use animation events because I need to retrieve a script from the parent. Is there a way to manage mecanim events more efficiently?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're caching the reference to `Amon` and calling its method whenever an animation event is invoked, which is relatively performant! If there's only one `Amon`, you could the class to a singleton and use its instance instead via `Amon.Instance` - although I feel the performance will be similar.

Comment: don't use a Singleton.. It potentially breaks more than it solves here, e.g. not having only one anymore later for whatever reason ^^